# How to make it easy for the end user to install all of my dependencies in Python?

Tags: python, pip, windows-installer, setuptools

I've built a program that has a couple of dependencies, and I am wondering how to make it as easy as possible for end-users at my company to install and use the program.

They will have no problem downloading Python and getting the program to run, and I can help them troubleshoot a bit. But I don't want to make them run multiple pip commands, especially not more involved ones like for the python snowflake connector ([installation info here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/python-connector-install.html#step-1-install-the-connector)) which requires them to run pip commands where they need to input their python version and the desired version of the package to download.

It seems like a simple requirements.txt might not be sufficient, since the snowflake connector requires downloading the list of dependencies from a live webpage. I considered using setup.py, which seems interesting, but apparently this is for python *packages*, and my program is rather a simulation and not a tool to be used by other programmers, as such I didn't think of it as a package.

As such I would benefit greatly from any recommendations on best practices to help my users install their dependencies - some degree of work is okay (it doesn't have to be just a one-click-install), but I'm looking for an alternative that is easier than running a bunch of verion-dependent pip commands.

The program will use Python 3.9, which is the most recent version compatible with my dependencies.

Comment: Is dependencies available in exe/msi format?

Comment: @VivekJaiswal The dependencies here are all Python packages, some of which come from a live list on the internet. I don't think they are all available in exe or msi format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use PyInstaller (Normal Users)

> PyInstaller can bundle your script and all its dependencies into a
> single executable named myscript (myscript.exe in Windows).

https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/operating-mode.html

You can dockerize your app (Developer Users)

https://www.docker.com/blog/how-to-dockerize-your-python-applications/